# I have recovery issues in my Gateway nv series laptop

Tags: windows-7, gateway

Helo

i wanted to restore os from my recovery drive. but because of some issues i could not do that.
so i had my recovery dvds which i made when i bought laptop. these are three dvds. so i inserted one dvd and installation started. and it asked for second dvd and i inserted but it is not taking it. once i did installtion with this three dvds but now it is not taking second dvd. So because of this type of failure i install trial version of windows 7 and take my backup.

after it i install Gateway recovery Management. and it is not working.
when i am repair my computer it is not showing that Image of recovery partition.

Please I need Help.

Comment: At this point, you may have to consider contacting Gateway support and purchasing anther set of recovery discs.

Comment: is there nothing i can do?

Comment: You can't see or use the recovery partition... you have already said that.  The recovery discs you made aren't working properly any more... you covered that too.  You could purchase a new copy of Windows, but that would cost more than a new set of recovery discs.  It might be an issue with your optical drive, or a bad stick of Ram, or another hardware problem that is causing the problems, but that would require checking your Ram with something like http://www.memtest86.com or taking the computer to a shop for diagnostics.

Comment: i checked in command prompt(diskpart) it is showing all drives with that recovery drive. and in there is one exe file with name 'Recover7.exe'. when i am trying to run it , it is giving some optical error and laptop going to restart.

Comment: What about hitting Alt+F10 when the laptop starts... you know, when you are seeing the Gateway Logo when you first turn on the laptop?  Does that bring you to the recovery program on the recovery partition?

Comment: yes is showing some hash code. no boot on partition 3 and giving two options in bottom. cancel and submit. and both options making laptop restart.

Comment: installing Win 7 trial separately killed the MBR that allowed you to boot to the recovery partition has been changed.  Thus that No Boot error.  You might be able to access it if you install EasyBCD http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/EasyBCD+Documentation+Home in your trial of Windows 7, but honestly, according to Gateway "If the ability to reinstall from the previous method is not available or fails, recovery of the Operating System will need to be from Recovery Media. If you do not have a set of Gateway Recovery Media, you may purchase the set online from http://us-store.gateway.com/rcd/

Comment: i think i can put MBR one more time by putting first recovery disk. is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your second DVD is it corrupt or not ?
if it does not trying recovery factory from your laptop, it can back your laptop  condition since you are installing at the first time (included Formatting all hard drive in your laptop).
so, be careful and think it first before recovery factory.

Comment: i check this second DVD and i can see all data. but on installation time it is not taking it. what should i do ?

Comment: can see all data does not mean DVD is not corrupt. maybe you can try it again by using another DVD (same type of laptop and operating system)

Comment: in my friend circle no one has Gateway laptop. but read this if you can help. i checked in command prompt(diskpart) it is showing all drives with that recovery drive. and in there is one exe file with name 'Recover7.exe'. when i am trying to run it , it is giving some optical error and laptop going to restart.

Comment: i think that is one of part file was corrupted. Because since i ever recovery my laptop it is successful (no problem)

Comment: have you any suggestions to recover is from command prompt. ?

Comment: i found the website of recovery windows 7. Try it first this is the link of website : http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/